# Генерация случайного числа заданного размера

Tags: c#, sql-server

В базе имеются юзеры, у каждого из них имеется уникальный пинкод (5-8 чисел, в рамках одной организации не могут быть участники с разной длиной кода). При добавлении нового участника, либо при импорте, нужно генерерировать уникальный пинкод. Сейчас реализовано на коленке,

1. берем все пинкоды из базы,
2. генерим случайное число и проверяем если такое уже имеется,

естественно когда участников много, то этот цикл очень долго работает. Подскажите варианты возможной реализации.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE pinCode = '12345678' LIMIT 1 и все.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов участники разбиты по организациям, организация сама настраивает возможную длину числа ( от 5 до 8 цифр). Т.е в рамках одной организации у участников длина пинкода одинаковая. Уникальность должна соблюдаться в рамках организации, а не в рамках всех участников

Comment: Одному мне кажется, что уникальность пинкода -- вредное и ненужное условие, да ещё и снижающее безопасность? Если вам при регистрации нового юзера выдаётся пин в 5 цифр, а через неделю уже в шесть -- можно для ранее регистрированных перебирать только пять (тогда ещё хватало уникальных свободных номеров), ну и перебирать проще КМК. А если я ХОЧУ пинкод 123456, то почему-то это мне должны запретить, если этот пинкод у кого-то уже есть, м?

Comment: @AK согласен, но таково бизнес требование. если длина пинкода меняется, то для всех участников происходит перегенерация

Comment: @S3Ga поправьте вопрос, у вас там про числа, а не цифры. Далее нужно считать вероятности, как часто может выпасть уже существующее число, учитывая размеры чисел. И добиваться, к примеру, чтобы только 1 раз из ста нужно было генерить число повторно и делать "лишний" запрос.

Comment: *когда участников много, то этот цикл очень долго работает* Не понял... у Вас что, есть наборы пинкодов, заполненные более чем наполовину? бред какой-то... Но в любом случае при хранении пинкода в числовом типе и наличии по этому полю индекса генерация отсутствующего пина даже при 90% заполнении должна быть весьма быстрой (и уж всяко менее секунды).

Comment: Вы не указали в вопросе 3-го пункта алгоритма, что происходит с сгенерированным кодом, пишется обратно в БД ? Если так, то могу предложить генерить коды сразу в БД. Причем скорее всего можно сделать одним запросом, для этого надо знать постановку задачи чуть конкретнее, как выбирается кому пересчитывать и есть ли какие то особенности генерации, кроме длины. И версию MS SQL (до 2008 функции rand() не было)

Comment: Так у вас пинкод из цифр или чисел? Если цифры, то собирайте это и храните как число - это проще же.

Comment: @tym32167 и как в числовом поле сохранить, например, пин-код 00123?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin а зачем хранить 00, если известно что длина пина = 5 ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70619/discussion-on-question-by-s3ga-----).

Comment: @DenisRubashkin в чем проблема сохранить число и длину числа вместо портянки чисел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю генерировать pin-коды на стороне SQL-Server. Основа получения кода заданной длинны `substring(concat(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())),ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))),2,6)`. Если длина pin-кода может быть больше 12 символов, то рекомендуется добавить еще один ABS(...). Длина создаваемого pin-кода регулируется последним параметром substring(). Второй параметр (с какого символа получаем) лучше оставить 2, в случае если он будет 1, в выборке не будет pin-кодов начинающихся на 0.

Теперь о том как это применять. Мы не можем гарантировать, что функция не вернет pin-код, который уже есть в БД, поэтому нам надо проверить его на существование и если он есть попробовать создать другой. Для быстрой проверки на существование на таблице надо создать индекс из полей (id-организации, pin-код), для быстрого поиска в пределах организации. Для повторения генерации, в случае провала, можно использовать рекурсивный CTE. Общая сложность запроса зависит от того, что именно нам надо получить. Генерация кода для одного пользователя довольно легка, так как нам надо проверить уникальность только по существующим пользователям в БД, но не надо проверять уникальность в пределах запроса. Делается это [примерно так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e193a8/3).

Если требуется создать с нуля много pin-кодов для одной организации целиком, то проверять наличие в БД не надо, так как все коды будут новые. Но при этом необходим контроль уникальности в пределах одного запроса. Как это сделать, показано ниже, в самом сложном виде запроса, который должен создать pin-коды для части пользователей организации, т.е. с контролем уникальности как в пределах запроса, так и в БД:

```
with CTE(userId,new_pin,level,plevel) as(
  select userId, cast(NULL as varchar),1,0
    from test
   where orgId=1  -- Создаем коды для этой организации
  union all
    select userId, (
       select new_pin from (
          select cast(substring(concat(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())),ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))),2,6) as varchar) new_pin
        ) X
              -- Проверка на существование в БД (для данной организации)
        where not exists(select 1 from test where pin=new_pin and orgId=1)
          and X.new_pin!=coalesce(A.new_pin,'0')
      ) new_pin,
      level+1,
      case when new_pin is null then plevel else plevel+1 end
    from CTE A where (new_pin is null and level<30) or plevel<10
),
Pins(userId,new_pin) as (
  select distinct userId,first_value(new_pin) over(partition by userId order by userId)
    from (
      select userId, new_pin,
             -- Нумеруем одинаковые pin-коды
             row_number() over(partition by new_pin order by new_pin) RN
        from CTE where new_pin is not null
    ) Y
  where RN=1 -- Берем только первый встреченный из одинаковых код, если их несколько 
)
select * from Pins
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e193a8/9)

Условия на level и plevel внутри запроса обеспечивают несколько попыток генерации в случае если такой код есть в БД и несколько вариантов, на случай повторов в пределах запроса. Сейчас заданы слишком большими, на случай если уже существует порядка 20-50% всех возможных кодов данного размера. В реальной жизни, при длине кода в 6 символов их можно спокойно уменьшать, что ускорит запрос.

И наконец, если нам надо не только получить коды но и сразу поменять их в БД, нам достаточно предложение `select * from Pins`, в конце запроса, заменить на:

```
update test
   set test.pin=Pins.new_pin
  from Pins
  join test on test.userId=Pins.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Берете кол-во использованных ПИНов К
2. Случайное число от 0 до К  (N)
3. Случайное число нужной разрядности в диапазоне [N]...[N+1] `Random.Next(Pin[N],Pin[N+1])`

Ну еще проверку, что Pin[N],Pin[N+1] не подряд.

Comment: А если подряд? И что-то я в равномерности распределения сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если подряд, то просто сдвинутся вперед. Чтобы у генератора от и до не совпадали.

Comment: А почему это _"сдвинутся вперед"_ будет работать быстрее, чем в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

В ряде случаев, наиболее простым вариантом будет сгенерировать все требуемые ПИН-коды заранее и выдавать их в случайном порядке.

Шаг 1. Создаем таблицу и заполняем ее последовательными данными (решение позаимствовал тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

```
DECLARE @BIT AS BIT = 0
select TOP 90000 IDENTITY(int,10000,1) AS pin, 0 AS is_taken
    INTO pins
    FROM        (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T2]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T4]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T8]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T16]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T32]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T64]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T128]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T256]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T512]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T1024]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T2048]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T4096]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T8192]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T16384]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T32768]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T65536]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @BIT [X] UNION ALL SELECT @BIT) [T131072]
ALTER TABLE pins ADD CONSTRAINT PK_pins PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (pin)
go
```

Шаг 2. Объявляем хранимую процедуру для выдачи нового ПИН-кода:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getnewpin @pin INT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE pins
    SET is_taken = 1,
        @pin = pin
    WHERE pin = (SELECT TOP 1 pin 
                 FROM pins WITH(UPDLOCK) 
                 WHERE is_taken = 0 
                 ORDER BY newid())
    SELECT @pin
END
```

Шаг 3. Генерируем новый пин-код по мере надобности:

```
DECLARE @newpin INT
EXECUTE sp_getnewpin @newpin
```

Попробовать на SQLFiddle, к сожалению, не получится - там в запросах не разрешается DML, поэтому возвращаемый результат пустой (или это я не умею его готовить?), но на настоящем сервере работает как часы - протестировал на трехзначных пинах в параллельных потоках, сгенерировалось строго 900 значений, без повторов, потом стали выдаваться NULL-ы.